# How to change this humorous output style in pycaret+colab?

Tags: colab, pycaret

My eyes are on fire. I checked the documents, there is just an option to disable all outputs, and I just need to clean this dirty yellow cells.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to change about the output? Do you want to remove the yellow highlights? Reformat the data in another way?

Comment: Yes, change yellow outputs and TT column

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70766518/how-to-change-ipython-error-highlighting-color

Comment: Thanks to Memristor, this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70766518/how-to-change-ipython-error-highlighting-color